# Reading text file line by line using streamReader in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read text file line by line using streamReader .
I am taking file path from textbox but it reads only last line

this is my code for replacing stop keywords in text file .

```
try {
    string line;
    string path = textBox1.Text;
    MessageBox.Show("Process is start");
    //string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(richTextBox1.Text);
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
    MessageBox.Show(" process start reading file");

    string[] stopWord = new string[] {
        "is", "are", "am", "could", "will", "ing", "er", "est"
    };

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        // MessageBox.Show("in while");
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@
        "D:\temp.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter file1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
        file1.WriteLine();
        foreach(string word in stopWord) {
            //line = line.Replace(word,Environment.NewLine);
            line = line.Replace(word, "");
        }
        file1.WriteLine(line);
        file1.Close();
    }
    /*Converting text file into binary */
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why not `string text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\temp.txt"); foreach (string word in stopWord) text.Replace(word, String.Empty); File.WriteAllText(path, text);`. Is there any requirement in both files to be open at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
string lines="";
 FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@
    "D:\temp.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter file1 = new StreamWriter(fs1);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    // MessageBox.Show("in while");       
    file1.WriteLine();
    foreach(string word in stopWord) {
        //line = line.Replace(word,Environment.NewLine);
        line = line.Replace(word, "");

    }
    lines +=line +Environment.Newline;
}
    file1.WriteLine(lines);
    file1.Close();
```

you were creating new file1 in your while loop, that's why it showed only the last line. Replace your while loop with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `File` to simplify this code:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path);

foreach (var word in stopWords) text = text.Replace(word, "");

File.WriteAllText(@"D:\temp.txt", text);
```

It is much less customizable and it will read the whole file for processing, which may cause performance problems.
However, if you aren't going to work with big amount of data, you can use this approach as it is much shorter and convenient to work with.

Comment: This is fundamentally very different code. Instead of reading a line out at a time, like the OP asks, you are reading the whole file, which maybe many GB in size.

Comment: @Aron Yes, I understand. I didn't mean "replace your code", I meant "you can also use this if suitable". I forgot to mention it in my answer. I have updated it. Thank you :)